# Access denied for mts0 & mts1.googleapis.com in blackberry10 webworks application

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I am working on a Blackberry 10 application developed using Blackberry10 webworks SDK 1.0.4.11.  I am using Google maps in my application. In my config file I have given access to all the sites that I am using in my app lik this

```
<access uri="https://csi.gstatic.com" subdomains="true">
<feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
</access>

<access uri="http://www.google.com" subdomains="true">
<feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
</access>

<access uri="https://maps.googleapis.com" subdomains="true">
<feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
</access>

<access uri="https://maps.gstatic.com" subdomains="true">
<feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
</access>

<access uri="https://mts.googleapis.com" subdomains="true">
<feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
</access>

<access origin="https://mts1.googleapis.com" subdomains="true">
<feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
</access>

<access origin="https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt" subdomains="true">
<feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
</access>

<access uri="https://mts0.googleapis.com" subdomains="true">
<feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
</access>

<access uri="https://mts0.googleapis.com/vt" subdomains="true">
<feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
</access>

<access uri="https://csi.gstatic.com" subdomains="true">
<feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
</access>

<access uri="https://fonts.googleapis.com" subdomains="true">
<feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
</access>

<access uri="https://themes.googleusercontent.com" subdomains="true">
<feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
</access>
```

But I am getting

" Access to " https://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@2340000&src=apiv3&hl=en-US&x=15&y=15&z=5&scale=5 " not allowed " alert when I try to load the map.

The same access denial error comes when I access https://mts1.googleapis.com too.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I need to disable web security. These mts0, mts1, mts2 , mts3 are blacklisted ones. We need to whitelist it, to make it work using this code...

<feature id="blackberry.app">
    <param name="websecurity" value="disable" />
</feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use any web service in your application you have to add these lines in your 'config.xml' file.Otherwise you wont get permission to access those sites.Hope this helps :)

```
<access uri="http://www.address1.com" subdomains="true">
    <feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
    <feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
  </access>
 <access uri="http://www.address2.com" subdomains="true">
    <feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
    <feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
  </access>
```